# Reset FileOptions.DeleteOnDispose in FileStream possible?

Tags: c#, filestream

in the FileStream I sometimes use the FileOptions.DeleteOnDipose features which automatically - as the name says - deletes the files when I call the Dispose() method. What if I wnat to decide otherwise during the application and I want to remove the flag again and keep the file?

Since this is a feature from the original WindowsAPI I had a look there, but I couldn't find a solution.

Does someone of you know how to reset the flag, if possible?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: No, the flag is used in the CreateFile() call, it cannot be withdrawn.

Comment: For the record, I believe it is possible to use NtSetInformationFile to set the FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION info class (http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.html#FileDispositionInformation). That's undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm that case I would use *regular* dispose, and handle the file deletion (or not) in a `finally` block. I don't know of a way to reset that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change file flags once you created a file. You can only change file attributes. I also took a look at Windows API and only method that is exposed is `SetFileAttributes` which allows you to change attributes only.

You should think of different logic to accomplish this, like implement `System.IO.File.Delete()` by your own when you want file to be deleted and don't relay to `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.

Sample:

```
public class FileStreamEx : System.IO.FileStream
{
    private bool _deleteOnDispose = false;

    public FileStreamEx(string path, ....) : base(path, ...) { }

    public bool DeleteOnDispose
    {
        get { return _deleteOnDispose; }
        set { _deleteOnDispose = value; }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_deleteOnDispose)
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(this.Name);
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you are right, I tried this solution before, but the problem is, that if the application is terminated so that no Finalizers can run the file is still kept in the filesystem. The DeleteOnDispose attribute ensures that the files is deleted afterwards.

Comment: @Martin Sedlmair: I understand your problem. Eventually what you could do is when you open the file, store it's path to registry and when you close your file, delete path from registry. If app crashes, on next first startup check if path in registry exists, if it does that means app crashed and you can to delete that file... (something like that) :-)

Comment: Sounds like a nice solution. I think I rather keep it as it is and live with the problem. At least it's not a problem, it's only not nice if I would keep the file. ;-)